# ¿Como actualizar todos los atributos de una clase que dependan de un atributo específico?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase, class

```
Class dibujo():
        Def __init__(self, cantidad, dimensiones):
            Self.dimensiones = dimensiones
            Self.calculos = función(cantidad, self.dimensiones)
```

Suponiendo que necesito el atributo self.dimensiones para hacer los cálculos en "self.calculos" pero luego de crear el objeto quiero ir ajustando el valor de "self.dimensiones", ¿ Como haría para que el valor de self.calculos se vaya actualizando sobre la misma instancia de esa clase?

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar el decorador @property

en lugar de definir la propiedad en init la conviertes en una función que se llama como una propiedad.

```
class ejemplo:
    def __init__(self, cantidad, dimensiones):
        # creamos una propiedad privada que nos guarde los valores
        self._dimensiones = dimensiones
        self.cantidad = cantidad
        self.calculos = 0
        self.calcula()
```

Al "pedir" la propiedad se ejecuta la función asociada,

```
    @property
    def dimensiones(self):
        return self._dimensiones
```

Al definir el setter de la propiedad podemos definir el comportamiento al asignar un valor

```
    @dimensiones.setter
    def dimensiones(self, value):
        self._dimensiones = value
        # operaciones que quieras que se hagan
        self.calcula()

    def calcula(self):
        self.calculos = funcion(self.cantidad, self.dimensiones)
```

Comment: Concisa la explicación, funciono a la perfección, apenas lo estoy probando como tal hoy porque lo previo era largo. Una duda: es pythonico dejar esos metodos de setter y calcula sin un return al final?

Comment: no se ha puesto un return porque recalculas un valor de la clase, adicionalmente puedes poner un return pero en este caso es innecesario, no todas las funciones deben devolver algo